# ImageReader incompatible pixel format

Tags: java, android, screenshot, pixelformat

I have a problem with ImageReader, when I try to acquire image from it.

`imageReader.acquireLatestImage()` always returning null, or throwing UnsupportedOperationException where main problem is pixel format.
From exception message I can read, that I need to configure ImageReader to acquire images with pixel format equal to 0x5 (binary 5), but I try to get it with 0x1 or 0x2 or 0x3 (I try some options out).

That's how ImageReader is configured:

```
ImageReader.newInstance(rawDisplayMetrics.widthPixels, rawDisplayMetrics.heightPixels, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
```

So, when I try to configure it with 0x5 it obviously throwing an error, there is no 5 constant value in `android.graphics.PixelFormat` class.

Is that just hardware good known problem, or something with rooting telephone?

I tested it on rooted Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 6.0.1 Cyanogen Mod 13.0.20160711 (maybe there is any bug in this version of mod? I don't really want to change it just for tests cause it's working now like charm)

Anyone faced similar problem?

Comment: it would be useful to include the exact error message

Comment: Any news on this ?

Comment: It was a problem with Cyanogen Mod 13..., after installing different system problem gone. On my tablet I don't have such problem as well, so.. Yeah, it's definitely a cyanogen mod issue.